# Intel x86 or AMD64?

Tags: ubuntu

I don't know whether to use Intel x86 or AMD64 image on my computer. I have a 2011 Macbook Air with a Sandy Bridge i7 and Intel HD3000 which is definately capable of handling 64 bits, however, due to the wording on [Ubuntu's website](https://ubuntu-mate.org/vivid/). It says that Intel x86 should be used on almost all pcs as well as newer Intel Macs. Since I clearly have an Intel Mac, should I be using Intel x86 image?

> Download
>
> Ubuntu MATE is currently available for four architectures, PC (Intel x86), 64-bit PC (AMD64), Mac (PowerPC) and IBM-PPC (POWER5) and Raspberry Pi 2 aarch32 (ARMv7).
>
> **PC (Intel x86)** For almost all PCs. This includes most machines with Intel/AMD/etc type processors and almost all computers that run Microsoft Windows, as well as newer Apple Macintosh systems based on Intel processors. Choose this if you are at all unsure.
>
> **64-bit PC (AMD64)** Choose this to take full advantage of computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the Intel x86 images instead.
>
> **Mac (PowerPC) and IBM-PPC (POWER5)** For Apple Macintosh G3, G4, and G5 computers, including iBooks and PowerBooks as well as older IBM OpenPower 7xx machines.

Comment: How big is your RAM?

Comment: If you're ram is >= 4GiB, you need a 64 bit operating system or if you plan on increasing it to that size, you need a 64 bit operating system, otherwise a 32 bit operating system is enough. A 32 bit operating system will take a little bit less space and a little bit less RAM at runtime. It might perform slightly worse on certain operations (+slightly better on others; the performance characteristics of the two tend to be very similar).

Comment: You _can_ install 64bit os even on intel macs, even on a 2007 macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely choose 64 bit. You still could launch 32 bit applications, e.g. 32 bit wine. The only downside you could meet is *a development* of projects that you want to be compiled to 32 bit architecture, but for that case there's a well working workaround with *lxc* tools.

The upside you would get is a better performance. 64 bit code have to be faster, and there are reasons:

- Function call convention. In general 32 bit code passes parameters through a stack — which is a memory; while 64 bit code uses CPU registers for passing arguments. Even supposedly that CPU cache would reduce the performance hit to the minimal, there's an overhead of copying parameters into a stack.
- More registers size — a CPU register now could hold two times bigger value.
- More registers number — 64 bit code have an access to two times more number of registers. This means that in cases where 32 bit code have to store a value into a memory, 64 bit code could just leave it in CPU.

There's a drawback though that pointers now have two times bigger size, but I tend to think that upsides are still stronger.

Comment: Isn't [x32](https://lwn.net/Articles/456731/) a completely different ABI, the same as neither i386 nor amd64/x86_64? I don't think any version of Ubuntu is compiled for that architecture.

Comment: @Celada well, I didn't meant an exact ABI; actually I didn't know that there's an ABI that is called exactly `x32 ABI`. I used to use as synonims *x32/x64* → *32 bit/ 64 bit*. To be clear: there is a number of different call conventions for both 32 and 64 bit code, but there's a tendency that 32 bit conventions use stack more often than 64 bit code. The reason is obviously a smaller number of registers. Thank you, I'll edit the answer to replace the "synonims" 

Comment: 64-bit code isn't always faster, that depends on what the code does. x86_64 is *usually* faster than x86_32, primarily because x86_64 has more registers. But 64-bit code can also be slower, moslty with symbolic code (code that manipulates a lot of pointers), because of the additional memory pressure.

Answer (score 5):

x86 is the 32-bit version that should run on *most* Intel/AMD 'PC' hardware and later Apples.

AMD64 is the 64-bit version that should run on *modern* Intel/AMD 'PC' hardware and later Apples.

32-bit architecture has a 4GB RAM limit (with some chipsets being able to support PAE and up to 64GB RAM) whereas the 64-bit can address a vast amount of RAM.

The Intel i7 is most definitely a 64-bit CPU, therefore you should consider using the AMD64 architecture.  The x86 will also work, but you may reach the 4GB RAM limit.

[Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_1410_32v64) benchmarked Ubuntu 14.10 as both 32-bit and 64-bit and the latter came out on top in most test cases.

Unless you've a reason to use 32-bit, go for the 64-bit (AMD64).

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu x32 uses PAE, so there's more than 4Gb addressable.

Comment: @Hi-Angel - thanks. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: What's confusing here is that the *AMD* in AMD64 says to my subconsciousness that I'm dealing with an architecture that is *not* compatible with Intel 86 machines like Core 2, i5, i7 and Modern Xeon.  For example, I don't think Intel Itanium IA-64 compile programs are compatible with Core 2, i5, i7 and Modern Xeon so why (at first glance) should I presume AMD64 is?  The use of *AMD* in AMD64 was apparently done for marketing reasons, but  I feel it's highly misleading... See Jindal's post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/601553/what-is-the-difference-between-x86-64-amd64-and-64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Well, that isn't exactly "Ubuntu's website", is it? It's ubuntu-mate's web site (whatever that is — I don't know).

The text you quote is very misleading and arguably wrong in places. For example, "if you need full support for 32-bit code [...]" is just wrong, since Ubuntu supports 32-bit package installation even on 64-bit systems, so there is definitely no need to "downgrade" to 32-bit just because you need to install some 32-bit software.

More importantly, x86 arguably designates both 32-bit (i386) and 64-bit (amd64 or x86_64) systems, which makes it confusing terminology.

Really, if you have a 64-bit CPU it's very simple: you should install the 64-bit version. And if you try that and your CPU isn't 64-bit after all, you'll know it very quickly: it won't run at all, it won't even boot.